# Create a SQL view with conditions

Tags: mysql, view

I wanted to create a view that selected `animal_id`, `date` from `service_records` table with conditions of Canine type and bath service, but I got an error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' service_type='B'.

How should I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW dogs_bath_records 
AS
    SELECT animal_id, date 
    FROM service_records
    WHERE animal_type = 'Canine', service_type = 'B';
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `AND` for multiple conditions

```
CREATE VIEW dogs_bath_records AS
SELECT animal_id, date
FROM service_records
WHERE animal_type='Canine'
AND service_type='B';
```